# Determining if a Certain Equation is an Even (or Odd) Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried answering some questions found on the freely-given testpaper when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> The function $f(x) = e^{4x}$ ($-\pi < x < \pi$), which assumed to be periodic of period $2\pi$ is:
>
> A. Even function
>
> B. Odd function
>
> C. Neither odd nor even function
>
> D. None of these

**My work**

Since when does the equation $f(x) = e^{4x}$ becomes periodic? I don't know how to tackle this question because......$f(x) = e^{4x}$ was assumed to be
periodic.....I know some periodic functions.....like the sine function and the cosine function....but even if I know those periodic functions, it doesn't seem to fit to the equation above.

How do you determine if the function $f(x) = e^{4x}$ ($-\pi < x < \pi$), which assumed to be periodic of period $2\pi$, is an odd? or even? or neither? or the equation can't be odd or even?

Comment: Use the definition of an odd/even function. Check whether $f(-x) = \pm f(x)$ or not.

Comment: With regards to the periodicity, remember that $f(x)=e^{4x}$ only on $(-\pi, \pi)$, and that $f(x)$ can be different for other values of $x$. We assume it's periodic so by assumption, the shape of $f(x)$ is repeated for every $2\pi$ along we go

Comment: Notice that $f(-\pi/2)=e^{-2\pi}$ and $f(\pi/2)=e^{2\pi}$. It's obvious that they are neither equal nor one of them is the negative of the other, thus concluding it's neither even nor odd.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas what topic in math does these things being discussed?

Answer (score 0):

You know that $f(1)=e^4$ and that $f(-1)=e^{-4}$. Besides, you know that $e^{-4}\neq e^4$ and that $e^{-4}\neq-e^4$. Therefore, your function is neither odd nor even.